# Concatenate functions in PHP to use in an URL

Tags: php, function, concatenation, penetration-testing

I am penetration testing a web application and I need to concatenate two functions in one URL. (Yes, I already checked [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164022/how-to-concatenate-2-function-in-php) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154322/how-to-concatenate-2-function-in-php))

I am going to take the exact same code, because I did not understand why there is no proper answer to a legit question like this one. (psst, it's not about a backdoor or something)

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['function'])){ 
        $_GET['function'](); 
    } 
?>
```

Is there any possibility to create something like this?
`http://localhost/?function=shell_exec('ls') AND phpinfo`

Thank you for your help and I hope this time someone will take a legit question seriously instead of downvoting it to hell for no logical reason.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'function' when you say you want to concatenate them?

Comment: I think you're looking for eval: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: evaluating a string as PHP code might work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks extremely dangerous. You can pass a string separated with a semicolon for each function, like this
:

```
http://localhost/?function=shell_exec('ls');phpinfo
```

So your actual code would become:

```
if(isset($_GET['function'])){ 
        $functions =  explode(';',$_GET['function']); 
        foreach($functions as $function){ 
                $function(); 
        } 
}
```

You may also use the `eval` function:

```
http://localhost/?function=?eval=shell_exec('ls');phpinfo();
```

followed by `eval($_GET['eval']);`, as suggested in the comments below.

Comment: Your proposed solution won't work. Passing `shell_exec('ls')` to that function will result in an attempted execution of `shell_exec('ls')()` which is not valid.

Comment: How about `?eval=shell_exec('ls');phpinfo();` followed by `eval($_GET['eval']);` I mean the whole thing is already horrifying. :)

Comment: Yes, indeed. I agree :)

Comment: Well, you need a means of executing code within a string, and since we can't use `eval()`, we need to be able to produce code that is executed with the PHP `()` operator. Typing `?function=phpinfo` works, though if you want to do more damage you'll need something else.

Comment: Thank you, guys, I think this is what I need. +1 to everyone xD

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems here, I'll answer the question first.

Why not make it an array?

Url:

```
http://localhost/?function[]=phpinfo&function[]=bob
```

Code:

```
$functions = (array)$_GET['function'];
foreach($functions as $function) {
    $function();
}
```

The second problem is you aren't easily going to be able to pass in parameters as you have it above. You might need to do a little bit of regex first, but then you're on thin ice.

This is a huge guess, but something like:

```
$matches = [];
preg_match('/(\w+)\(('?(\w+)'?,?)+\)/', $functions, $matches);
```

You should then be able extract the function name and parameters (as long as they're strings) and call the function with the parameters. But that regex is obviously dodgy as anything :/

Comment: OP is pentesting this, not trying to run a function as described.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Clearly he wants to run phpinfo(), and exec('ls'); The answer he's currently looking at uses eval, and you yourself pointed out you can't just run it as `$func = 'function()'; $func();`. Perhaps the original question isn't clear enough as to what he wants to do, or perhaps I'm missing something? Arbitrarily throwing stuff at the url isn't pen testing.

Comment: Well, he says he is trying to pentest a site. I assume that he's found a vulnerability reflecting that of the code he's posted. What's the point of pentesting if you just modify the source file to be vulnerable? The point is to exploit the vulnerability as it stands. Unless OP is able to upload such files to the server as it is. If that is the case he is wasting his time doing this.

Comment: I think we interpreted the question differently, judging by his comment "evaluating a string as PHP code might work. Thank you!" I think he is editing PHP.